# valgrind shows unfreed memory

Tags: c, valgrind, free

My code is:

```
bool check(const char* word)
{
    char letter;
    node* nodes = malloc(sizeof(node));
    for (int i = 0; isalpha(word[i]) != 0; i++)
    {   
        letter = tolower(word[i]);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            if (root->children[(int)letter - 96] == NULL)
                return false; 
            nodes = root->children[(int)letter - 96];
        }        
        else
        {
            if (nodes->children[(int)letter - 96] == NULL)
            {
               return false;
            }
            nodes = nodes->children[(int)letter - 96];
        }       
    } 
    if (nodes->value == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;    
    free (&letter);
    free (nodes->children);
    free (&nodes->value);
    free (nodes);
}
```

valgrind says that I don't free variable created in line 4, but I don't understand why, as I free it at the end.

Comment: You don't free variables; you free memory blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines

```
if (nodes->value == 1)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

ensure that the function returns before it can `free` any memory.

Comment: And there are two early exits from within the loop that also leak memory.

Comment: I have fixed my silly mistakes, so now I gave free(nodes) before every return, but it still didn't solve the problem

Comment: You allocated memory for `*nodes` but didn't initialise it before doing `if (nodes->children[(int)letter - 96] == NULL)` so it's probably failing even before you try to `free(nodes)`.

Comment: You go on to `nodes = nodes->children[(int)letter - 96];` so goodness knows what you are trying to free! You have lost your allocated memory pointer to an uninitialised struct field.

Answer (score 1):

If a branch of your code returns from the function, the final `free(nodes)` won't be called, which is the case in your situation: you have multiple paths `return true` or `return false`.

In any case freeing a stack variable (as in `free(&letter)`) doesn't make any sense and it's an error, since it's not dynamically allocated. This applies also to sub-objects.

The golden rule is that you need a `free` for each `malloc/calloc`, in your code you have 1 `calloc` and 4 `free`, which means that you are releasing memory for things that are not allocated on the heap (`nodes->children, &nodes->value, &letter`)

Comment: I have fixed my silly mistakes, so now I gave free(nodes) before every return, but it still didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this code is properly formatted?

Not only does your function finish before the `if (nodes->value)...`, but also both of the branches return a value. That means you'd never progress from the `if` part to the `free(...)` statements.

Also you don't ever have to free local/stack values. `free(&letter)` is invalid and will likely cause a crash.